# How can I improve my application's memory use?

Tags: c#, memory-usage

I am writing a C# application, and can see the memory usage increasing as the running time of the application increases.

Are there any tools or techniques I could monitor my application's memory use, identify memory leaks and generally improve my application's memory use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following resources may help you

**For Tool**

- [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) 
  As good as monitoring the memory is by itself, you're probably thinking of memory profiling to identify leaks or stale objects.
- [.NET Memory Profiling](http://www.softwareverify.com/dotNet/memory/index.html)
  This tool helped me to solve many different issues related to memory management in C# .Net application I have to work with.
- [Tool Mentor](http://sce.uhcl.edu/helm/rationalunifiedprocess/toolment/purify/tm_purfymngcode.htm) This tool describes how to use Rational Purify
  to profile and improve memory usage in a managed code application.
  This tool mentor is applicable for use with systems running the
  Microsoft .NET Framework on Microsoft Windows.
- [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) It is a clever tool that gives you a picture of what is
  taking up the memory in a running process.
- [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) This tool finds memory leaks and optimize memory usage
  in your .NET application.

**For Concepts &Techniques**

- [Understanding Visual Studio (2010) memory consumption.](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20140617092751/http://www.melborp.net/post/2011/08/18/Understanding-Visual-Studio-%282010%29-memory-consumption.aspx)

Comment: I have used and been happy with redgate products. They provide the [ANTS Memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler&gclid=CLnn1_POsrMCFcqY4AodD2sA_Q)

Comment: @Ben, Yes. Another good one. I have added this at answer.

Comment: Jetbrains (makers of resharper) dotTrace too